# "@" in the password breaks exporting proxy variable

Tags: proxy

I have at the rate in the password (@) that I use to authenticate and use internet in my college. But to set proxy settings from the terminal we have to separate password and proxy host with @. Ubuntu is mistaking my @ in the password to this @.

Unfortunately I cannot change the password as the site, through which I can change by password, is down. And to set the proxy I did this: `sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc` in terminal and in the end of this file added this line

```
export http_proxy=username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

with my details.

Comment: Did you try escaping it `\@` or putting it in quotation marks `"@"`? It's a bit hard to guess the context, e.g. the command, you're using the password in.

Comment: The handling of the http_proxy variable is performed by whatever utility you are trying to use (wget, curl, ...). You should file a bug report for the corresponding utility.

Comment: @con-f-use: the normal way of escaping in a URL would be `%40` rather than `\@`.  There might be some tools that accept backslash escaping, but they aren't processing the URL correctly.